# Is there a way I can be 100% sure whether my computer is virus free?

Tags: virus

First of all I have asked this question here because this site is also for computer software. If this is the wrong platform then sorry please transform this question to the right platform mods.

Ya so recently I got a warning from Quick Heal stating a virus has entered my PC and I clicked on Remove. However I am still scared that it might be on my PC yet. I ran Quick Heal Total Security and it showed no virus. I ran Windows Security and it showed No Threat Detected. But can I be 100% assure by these results that there is no virus in my PC? Is there a way I can check if there is a virus in my PC or not?

Comment: In the purist sense, you cannot be "100% sure" there is no virus on _any_ running computer system. To do this you would have have validated everything from the base hardware upward.

Comment: Okay then 60-80% sure? @roaima

Comment: Do you trust Quick Heal? If not, why are you using it? If you do, and it says all is good, then you have to assume it knows what it's talking about

Comment: @roaima because in both my computer a same virus came so I felt that maybe virus is spreading through network and quick heal ig can't scan network

Comment: Run Malwarebytes as an additional check.